# I want to view data when I request to page index in javascript, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

as page index is changed, I want to make page that is matched for page index

below is my code logic

```
 for (var i in items) {                                                                                                                                
      if (index == 1) {                                                                                                                                   
        for (var j = 0; i < 10; j++){                                                                                                                     
        }                                                                                                                                                
      } else if (index == 2) {                                                                                                                            
        for (var j = 11; i < 20; j++) {                                                                                                                   
        }                                                                                                                                                 
      } else if (index == 3) {                                                                                                                            
        for (var j = 21; i < 30; j++) {                                                                                                                  
        }                                                                                                                                                 
      } else if (index == 4) {                                                                                                                            
        for (var j = 31; i < 40; j++){                                                                                                                   
        }                                                                                                                                                 
      }
```

I want to do this code is changed from simple to logical
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you are using `i` as a variable name in an outer and inner loops.

Comment: Your edit didn't get rid of the `i` everywhere: `i < 10` and `i++` should be changed as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take 2 global variables

```
var curr_page = 1;
var page_limit = 10;

// variables required for for loop
var start_index = 1;
var end_index =1 10;
```

and use the below function to calculate start and end index,

```
function calculate_currrent_index(curr_page) {
  start_index = (curr_page - 1)*page_limit;
  end_index = curr_page*page_limit
}
```

in for loop, you can use this as

```
for(i=start_index; i<= end_index, i++)
```

no need for if conditions now,

On clicking the pagination 1,2,3,4 ... etc
just call

```
calculate_currrent_index(1)
// here 1 is the clicked page number
```

I hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to optimise your code is like this:

```
for (var i in items) {  
    var startPosition = (index * 10);
    for (var j = startPosition ; j < startPosition + 10; j++){  

       ;//Some voodoo-code magic here.
    }
}
```

Comment: you are using `i` as a variable name in outer and inner loops.

Comment: @strah Whoops, I copied the errors from OPs question. Thanks.